# Why does Ubuntu crash when I suspend or close my lid?

Tags: suspend, lid, capslock

Whenever I close my lid, or manually suspend, Ubuntu won't go back to normal and the caps lock key randomly blinks. How can I fix this? I really want to be able to close my lid without leaving my laptop on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be VirtualBox. I uninstalled VirtualBox & it started suspending correctly again. Anyway, thanks!