# Permanent Blank Screen after lid close?

Tags: 14.04, suspend, laptop, hdmi

I am using Ubuntu on my Hp M6 Envy laptop.

I closed my lid to move with my laptop and by the time (10 mins) i opened it the screen was totally blank not black , blank. I restarted many times with no results. Got home and connected the laptop to my tv via hdmi and it works fine. What could be the problem here? Over the past months i know ubuntu has been known to crash my laptop after suspending.

Comment: Just for verifying can you please boot in from a LiveDVD and see if everything works fine. We can proceed from there.

Comment: It only boots on the secondary monitor but the touchscreen on my laptop still functions fine

Comment: ref: http://askubuntu.com/questions/57407/why-does-ubuntu-crash-when-i-suspend-or-close-my-lid it might be the issue with your virtualbox if it is installed. Uninstall it and check.

Answer (score 1):

By the fact that "it works fine" on TV via HDMI, I am afraid that there is a problem with your laptop screen hardware. Please consult on superuser.com

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Couldn't it be something where ubuntu is forcing the screen to act like the lid is closed still? I

Comment: @MicahMessiah It may well be OS related. Do you see text on the screen during POST? If so, it's not hardware related (probably). If you see no text during the boot process (or manufacturer's logo) then its hardware related.

Comment: Totally blank screen. I was jsut hoping i wouldnt have to resort to repairing hardware wise. I figured it would be ubuntu seeing that it happened right after the usual problematic lid close